# Two sums Leetcode python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have recently started coding in Python. I appreciate if anyone could answer my question. Thank you.

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
Example:
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]

This is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            j=i+1
            while j<len(nums):
                if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                    print(i,j)                    
                else:
                    i=i+1
```

The output I'm getting:
Output limit exceeded
0 1
0 1
0 1........

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with code? I know we can use enumerate and do. But I want to know the reason for getting "Output limit exceeded"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slow, because you have nested loops (`for` and `while`). So for large inputs, you get TimeOut error.

Try to convert `nums` to dictionary, where keys will be numbers and values indices. That way, you can check if you have second number in O(1) time:

```py
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 9

nums = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(nums)}
for val, i in nums.items():
    if target - val in nums:
        print(i, nums[target - val])
        break
```

Prints:

```
0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers point out other problems with performance that would cause a Time limit exceeded error and how to fix them (and in the process, fix your real problem by side-effect), but miss the problem that causes your observed Output limit exceeded error. Figured I'd explain the actual problem so you know what it means if you see it again.

Your final line is `i=i+1` when you almost certainly meant `j=j+1`. Since you never change `j`, the `while` loop either never runs (when `len(nums) == 1`), or runs forever (`len(nums) > 1`). Of course, since you *do* change `i`, eventually `i` exceeds the legal indices for `nums`, and your code dies with an `IndexError`. The traceback for that `IndexError` is almost certainly longer than the defined limit on output for such a simple problem, causing the problem you see.